# Best substitute, successor or alternative for ASIHTTP for a download queue

Tags: iphone, ios, queue, progress-bar, asihttprequest

I've recently read the news on http://allseeing-i.com that ASIHTTP is being discontinued. I have much respect for the makers of the library. However, I am now looking for a substitute that also supports queued download (multithreaded) on iOS, that also supports a progress bar with appropriate information.

Is there any (hopefully lightweight) library, that is in an active development livecycle? ARC support would also be much appreciated.

Many thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is being lauded as a successor to ASIHTTPRequest. It is based on operation queues, and in my experience it works reasonably well. You could probably do what you want to do without a third-party library, but if you want to make it a little easier on yourself, a combination of `AFURLConnectionOperation` subclasses and the `AFHTTPClient` class will do nicely.

Comment: Note that although some work has been done on making it ARC-compatible, the official mainline of AFNetworking code is not ARC-compatible. In the meantime, it's quite easy to apply -fno-objc-arc to the relevant files.

Comment: I miss the simplicity of ASIHTTTP setQueueDidFinishSelector... Any replacements for AFNetworking rather than the NSOperationQueue KVO observing? That is kinda ugly..

Comment: Well, the `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:` method on the `AFHTTPRequestOperation` operation class allows you to set an arbitrary block to be called on success or failure, which to me is even more elegant than using the target/action pattern.

Comment: I meant for a queue, not for a single op

Comment: Ah, I misread. I suppose you could subclass `AFHTTPClient` to encapsulate the KVO code and call your own custom block or target/action when you observe a change. Or just hack it in directly.

Comment: I already subclassed it (needed to override setCompletionBlock), will try KVO inside it :)

Answer (score 5):

You may want to look at [MKNetworkKit](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit). In its words:

> MKNetworkKit's goal was to make it as feature rich as ASIHTTPRequest yet simple and elegant to use like AFNetworking

It has a number of very nice features for queuing and managing offline situations.

Comment: This library is deprecated now due to NSUrl Connection Depricated.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote one recently. It's fully ARC compliant and fairly lightweight:

https://github.com/nicklockwood/RequestQueue

As of version 1.2 it supports download and upload progress bars (see the included ProgressLoader example).

Rather than make a monolithic framework like ASI, I've tried to keep this as simple as possible. That means you are free to mix and match it with other libraries for stuff like POST parameter generation, JSON parsing, etc.

Comment: Looks great.  Really glad to get rid of GTMHTTPFetcher.